# Variable does not return in IF()

Tags: php, laravel

I got two variables:

> $links->first()->id and $last_inserted

If I echo both, returns normally...  But if I put:

```
if($links->first()->id == $last_inserted): //line: 277
   //return view("site.list.links_home.nolink");
endif;
```

Returns:

> {message: "Trying to get property of non-object", exception:
>   "ErrorException",…} exception : "ErrorException" file :
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\gloober\app\Http\Controllers\Site\SiteController.php"
>   line : 277 message : "Trying to get property of non-object" trace :
>   [{file:
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\gloober\app\Http\Controllers\Site\SiteController.php",
>   line: 277,…},…]

Comment: My guess, `$links` isn't an object, of has no object returned from `first()` (e.g. it's an empty collection)

Answer (score 0):

It means the `$links` is empty. Use the [`optional()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-optional) helper:

```
if (optional($links->first())->id == $last_inserted)
```

Comment: The problem is that a variable "$links->first()->id" always exists, if I put "echo $links->first()->id;" returns "25". The way you are passing me, a condition does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`$links->first()->id`  is empty and causes the error. Add a check for that using [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

**Try:**

```
if(!empty($links->first()->id ) && $links->first()->id == $last_inserted): //line: 277
```

Comment: The problem is that a variable "$links->first()->id" always exists, if I put "echo $links->first()->id;" returns "25". The way you are passing me, a condition does not work.